# 'int' object has no attribute

Tags: python, django

Добрый день! Подскажите пожалуйста, в чем может быть ошибка `'int' object has no attribute 'channel_id'`

Использую `Django 1.11`

Вот код

```
isFind = False
        channels = Channels.objects.all()
        order = Order.objects.filter(status='Promote').order_by('-price_person')

        for usr in order.values_list('channel_id', flat=True):
            if usr.channel_id in channels.valuest_list('channel_id', flat=True):
                continue

            isFind = True
            mes = 'Подпишись на этот канал и вернись чтобы получить вознаграждение!'
            keyboard = telebot.types.InlineKeyboardMarkup()
            url_button = telebot.types.InlineKeyboardButton(text="Перейти к каналу", url='https://t.me/' + usr.channel_url)
            callback_button = telebot.types.InlineKeyboardButton(text='Проверить подписку', callback_data='check_subscribe')
            keyboard.row(url_button)
            keyboard.row(callback_button)
            bot.send_message(chat_id, mes, reply_markup=keyboard)

        current_id = usr.channel_id
        user.channel_id = current_id
        user.save()
```

Вот 2 модели

```
class Channels(models.Model):
    channel_id = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=True, blank=True)
    username = models.ForeignKey('BotUser', max_length=50, null=True, blank=True)


class Order(models.Model):
    channel_id = models.BigIntegerField(('ID канала'),null=True, blank=True)
    channel_url = models.CharField(('Cсылка канала'), max_length=50, null=True, blank=True)
    username = models.ForeignKey('BotUser', max_length=50, null=True, blank=True)
```

Comment: `for usr in order.values_list('channel_id', flat=True)` — ну как бы вы сами попросили в переменную `usr` запихнуть число `channel_id`, естественно что у числа не будет атрибута `channel_id`

Comment: Прочитайте описание метода `values_list()`